# Angular 1.5 - passing http post response to controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass an http response from my controller to a service, it works well except for getting the response to go into the controller here is my code below:

For my service

```js
app.factory('ApiService',function($http,Config,$q){

 return {
  login: function(payload,callBack){
   var deferred = $q.defer();
  $http({
         method:'POST',
         url:Config.baseUrl + '/api/login',
         data:payload,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       }).then(function successCallback(callBack){
         console.log(callBack);
         return deferred.resolve(callBack);
       }, function errorCallback(callBack){
         //deferred.reject(error);
         console.log(callBack);
         return deferred.reject(callBack);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
      }
 }

});
```

and for the Controller

```js
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope,$position,$rootScope,$state,ApiService) {


    $scope.forms = {
      'loginForm':''
    }  

    var payload ={
      'username':'',
      'password':''
    }
   
   $scope.userLogin = function(form){

      $scope.username = form.username.$modelValue;
      $scope.password = form.password.$modelValue;

      payload ={
        "username":$scope.username,
        "password":$scope.password
      }

      ApiService.login(payload, function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }

      
   

  });
```

Now I don't understand because when I `console.log()` the response I'm able to see it in the service but doing the same on the controller I'm getting nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
 ApiService.login(payload).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Because you are returning a promise in your service.
Also you don't need that callback parameter, because the `then` method on the promise is your callback when it finishes and you can access the data your resolve it with.

```
app.factory('ApiService',function($http,Config,$q){

return {
login: function(payload){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:Config.baseUrl + '/api/login',
        data:payload,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      }).then(function (result){             
         return deferred.resolve(result);
      }, function (result){
         return deferred.reject(result);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I have been looking for

Answer (score 3):

No need to make it complex. Simply return promise from `factory` and use it in `controller.`

factory:

```
app.factory('ApiService',function($http,Config,$q) {    
   return {
        login: function(payload) {
            return $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:Config.baseUrl + '/api/login',
                data:payload,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
              });
          }
        }
    });
```

in controller :

```
 ApiService.login(payload).then(function(data){
      // use response data    
   }, function(error) {
      // handle error
 });
```